# Properly append multiple element <div> with proper index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a multi-element and dependent div that asks the user to first pick a state. Once the state is picked, then it will provide users with the appropriate city in the state.

```
<form method="post">
  <div class="summary">
    <div class="trip">
      <select name="State" class="state">
        <option selected disabled>Choose a State</option>
        <option>California</option>
        <option>New York</option>
      </select>
      <select name="City" class="city" disabled="true">
        <option value="Z">Select a city</option>
      </select>
      <br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#result").hide();
  $("form").on("change", "select", function(){
    var current = $(this).index();
    if($(this).eq(current).val() == 'Z') {
      $(".city").eq(current).html("<option>Select a city</option>");
      $(".city").eq(current).attr('disabled', true);
    }
    else {
      if($(this).eq(current).val() == 'California') {
        $(".city").eq(current).html("<option>San Francisco</option><option>Los Angeles</option>");
        $(".city option:first").eq(current).attr('selected', 'selected');
        $(".city").eq(current).attr('disabled', false);
      }
      if($(this).eq(current).val() == 'New York') {
        $(".city").eq(current).html("<option>New York City</option><option>Albany</option>");
        $(".city option:first").eq(current).attr('selected', 'selected');
        $(".city").eq(current).attr('disabled', false);
      }      

      }
      });
  var maxAppend = 0;
  $("#add").click(function() {
    if (maxAppend >= 4) return;
    var additional = $(".trip").html();
    $(".trip").after(additional);
    maxAppend++;
  });
});
```

I want to allow the users to add the class "trip" up to four times. When I use append() or after() as show above. The index of the newly added item rests to 1, which cause the selected in the first trip to reset because it has the same index. What is the proper and elegant way of implementing this?

here is the link to the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L2bfmo69/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/L2bfmo69/5/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var additional = $(".trip").html();
  $("#result").hide();
  $("form").on("change", "select", function(){
    var current = $(this).index();
    if($(this).eq(current).val() == 'Z') {
      $(".city").eq(current).html("<option>Select a fare</option>");
      $(".city").eq(current).attr('disabled', true);
    }
    else {
      if($(this).val() == 'California') {
        $(this).next().html("<option>San Francisco</option><option>Los Angeles</option>");
        $(this).next().attr('disabled', false);
      }
      if($(this).eq(current).val() == 'New York') {
        $(this).next().html("<option>New York City</option><option>Albany</option>");
        $(this).next().attr('disabled', false);
      }      
      
      }
      });
  var maxAppend = 0;
  $("#add").click(function() {
   
    $(".summary").append('<div class="trip">' + additional + "</div>");
    if ($('.summary').children().length >= 4) {
      $('#add').prop('disabled', true);
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <div class="summary">
    <div class="trip">
      <select name="State" class="state">
        <option selected disabled>Choose a State</option>
        <option>California</option>
        <option>New York</option>
      </select>
      <select name="City" class="city" disabled="true">
        <option value="Z">Select a city</option>
      </select>
      <br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="nexttrip"></div>
  <button type="button" id="add">Add another trip</button>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit"> 
</form>
```

After 4 insert by the user I have disabled the add button.

Comment: A related question:  So I use a $.getjson to grab the city: The next() and $this has an index of -1. How do I fix it?    else {
      var city = $(this).val();
      $.getJSON('get_city/', {state_id: stateid}, function(data) {
        var city_choice = '<option value="Z">Select a city</option>';
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
          options_city+='<option value="'+data[i].pk+'">'+data[i].fields['name']+'</option>';
        }
      $(this).next().html(options_city);
      $(this).next().attr('selected', 'selected');
      $(this).next().attr('disabled', false); }):
    }

Comment: Would you be able to help with the above?

Comment: Please share the response of your getJson Ajax call. Will definitely help you out.

Comment: I'll post it to another question and tag you. Thanks!

Comment: here is the followup question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45046932/how-to-allow-independent-jquery-actions-on-two-dependent-select-fields