# How to allow independent jquery actions on two dependent select fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I have two selection (city, building) is the dependent on what the users choose for state.

```
<form method="post">
  <div class="summary">
    <div class="trip">
      <select name="State" class="state">
        <option selected disabled>Choose a State</option>
        <option>California</option>
        <option>New York</option>
      </select>
      <select name="City" class="city" disabled="true">
        <option value="Z">Select a city</option>
      </select>
      <select name="Building" class="building" disabled="true">
        <option value="Z">Select a building</option>
      </select>
      <br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
```

City and building is pull as json from an ajax call.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var additional = $('.trip').html();
  $('#result').hide();
  $('form').on("change", "select", function(){
    var current_index = $(this).index();

    if($(this).eq(current_index).val() == 'Z') {
      $('.city').eq(current_index).html("<option>Select a fare</option>");
      $('.city').eq(current_index).attr('disabled', true);
      $('.building').eq(current_index).html("<option>Select a fare</option>");
      $('.building').eq(current_index).attr('disabled', true);
    }
    else {
      var stateid = $(this).val();
      var current = $(this);
      $.getJSON('get_city/', {state_id: stateid}, function(data) {
        var options_city = '<option value="Z">Select a city</option>';
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
      options_city+='<option value="'+data[i].pk+'">'+data[i].fields['name']+'</option>';
    }
        current.siblings('.city').html(options_city);
        current.siblings('.city option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');
        current.siblings('.city').attr('disabled', false);
      });
      $.getJSON('get_building/', {state_id: stateid}, function(data) {        
        var options_building = '<option value="Z">Select a building</option>';
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
     options_building+='<option value="'+data[i].pk+'">'+data[i].fields['building']+</option>';
    }  
        current.siblings('.building').html(options_building);
        current.siblings('.building option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');
        current.siblings('.building').attr('disabled', false);
      });
    }
  });  
  $('#add').click(function() {
    if ($('.summary').children().length >= 4) return;
    $('.summary').append('<div class="trip">' + additional + "<div>");
  });
});
```

The output of the json AJAX for city looks like:

```
<option value="1">New York City</option>
<option value="2">Albany</option>
```

Similarly for buildings:

```
<option value="1">Empire State Building</option>
<option value="2">Penn Station</option>
```

The issue here is that when I select a city, the building select box resets and all of the options disappears. I know this is because the two getjson call is in the same function. How do I make it so that the selection of city and building are independent from each other?

jsFiddle is not that useful here but I have included it as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/1mxrs8yq/

Comment: @Shiladitya Here is the question

Comment: Thanks for sharing.... can you please share some data that you are receiving from .getJSON???

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/1mxrs8yq/3/

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var additional = $('.trip').html();
      $('#result').hide();
      $('form').on("change", "select[name='State']", function(){
        var current_index = $(this).index();
 
        if($(this).eq(current_index).val() == 'Z') {
          $('.city').eq(current_index).html("<option>Select a fare</option>");
          $('.city').eq(current_index).attr('disabled', true);
          $('.building').eq(current_index).html("<option>Select a fare</option>");
          $('.building').eq(current_index).attr('disabled', true);
        }
        else {
        
          var stateid = $(this).val();
          var current = $(this);
          var data = [{
           pk: 1,
            name: 'New York'
          },
          {
           pk: 2,
            name: 'Test2'
          }];
          
          //$.getJSON('get_city/', {state_id: stateid}, function(data) {
            var options_city = '<option value="Z">Select a city</option>';
            for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            options_city+='<option value="'+data[i].pk+'">'+data[i]['name']+'</option>';
          }
            
            $(this).next().html(options_city);
            $(this).next()[0].selectedIndex = 0;
            $(this).next().attr('disabled', false);
         // });
         var data1 = [{
           pk: 1,
            building: 'test24'
          },
          {
           pk: 2,
            building: 'test78'
          }];
         
          //$.getJSON('get_building/', {state_id: stateid}, function(data) {    
            var options_building = '<option value="Z">Select a building</option>';
            for(var i=0; i<data1.length; i++){
            options_building+='<option value="'+data1[i].pk+'">'+data1[i]['building']+'</option>';
          }  
            
            $(this).next().next().html(options_building);
            $(this).next().next()[0].selectedIndex = 0;
            $(this).next().next().attr('disabled', false);
          //});
        }
      });  
      $('#add').click(function() {
        if ($('.summary').children().length >= 4) return;
        $('.summary').append('<div class="trip">' + additional + "<div>");
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
      <div class="summary">
        <div class="trip">
          <select name="State" class="state">
            <option selected disabled>Choose a State</option>
            <option>California</option>
            <option>New York</option>
          </select>
          <select name="City" class="city" disabled="true">
            <option value="Z">Select a city</option>
          </select>
          <select name="Building" class="building" disabled="true">
            <option value="Z">Select a building</option>
          </select>
          <br><br>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <button type="button" id="add">Add another trip</button>
```

In the solution I have commented out the getJSON. and assume the data would be in certain format. Instead of getJSON data I create two variable **data** & **data1** for **city** & **building** dropdowns respectively.

Comment: I think the problem is with $.getjson. $(this) doesn't work when you are within the function. Typically $(this) gets an index value from 0. When it is within the $.getjson, the index value becomes -1 and therefore next() doesn't work. That's why I tried siblings. But that doesn't solve it either.

Comment: Check this out https://jsfiddle.net/1mxrs8yq/4/ .. Here I hold the "this" of select element to "that" and used it. Give a try, because $.getJSON "this" is overwriting your element's "this".

Comment: Doing this is similar to what I did with var current = $(this).  So I think that is correct. However, I think running $.getjson in a row, when I select an option for city, its runs the getjson for buildings too, which resets the value for the second select.  I think the problem is running too getjson consecutively, no?

Comment: Here I have create alive example with getJSON. https://jsfiddle.net/1mxrs8yq/6/ . Have a look .

Comment: Ok. I discovered the issue. In my original code, when I select a state, The options for city and building shows up properly. However, once I select a value for city (value = 3), the stateid variable seems to be rewritten to another value( from 3 to 1). and therefore the $.getjson function grab some weird results. Do you know why this is? It doesn't break on yours because you don't pass it a variable into $.getjson.

Comment: I see. stateid is being rewritten by $this, because the select is on the city element now.

Comment: I was wondering if you might take a look at this.  I think it's the variable stateid and running $.getjson every time a city, or building is selected that is causing the problem.  When you select a city then a building. The state of the city selection is reset to its initial state. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45064373/selecting-an-option-is-resetting-another-depending-selection-box