# Selecting an option is resetting another depending selection box

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have two selection (city, building) is the dependent on what the users choose for state.

```
<form method="post">
  <div class="summary">
    <div class="trip">
      <select name="State" class="state">
        <option selected disabled>Choose a State</option>
        <option value="1">California</option>
        <option value="2">New York</option>
      </select>
      <select name="City" class="city" disabled="true">
        <option value="Z">Select a city</option>
      </select>
      <select name="Building" class="building" disabled="true">
        <option value="Z">Select a building</option>
      </select>
      <br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
```

City and building is pull as json from an ajax call.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var additional = $('.trip').html();
  $('#result').hide();
  $('form').on("change", "select", function(){
    var current_index = $(this).index();
    if ($(this).is('.state')) {
      var stateid = $(this).val();
    }
    else {
      var stateid = $(this).siblings('.state').val();
    };
    if($(this).eq(current_index).val() == 'Z') {
      $('.city').eq(current_index).html("<option>Select a fare</option>");
      $('.city').eq(current_index).attr('disabled', true);
      $('.building').eq(current_index).html("<option>Select a fare</option>");
      $('.building').eq(current_index).attr('disabled', true);
    }
    else {
      var current = $(this);
      $.getJSON('get_city/', {state_id: stateid}, function(data) {
        var options_city = '<option value="Z">Select a city</option>';
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
      options_city+='<option value="'+data[i].pk+'">'+data[i].fields['name']+'</option>';
    }
        current.siblings('.city').html(options_city);
        current.siblings('.city option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');
        current.siblings('.city').attr('disabled', false);
      });
      $.getJSON('get_building/', {state_id: stateid}, function(data) {        
        var options_building = '<option value="Z">Select a building</option>';
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
     options_building+='<option value="'+data[i].pk+'">'+data[i].fields['building']+</option>';
    }  
        current.siblings('.building').html(options_building);
        current.siblings('.building option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');
        current.siblings('.building').attr('disabled', false);
      });
    }
  });  
  $('#add').click(function() {
    if ($('.summary').children().length >= 4) return;
    $('.summary').append('<div class="trip">' + additional + "<div>");
  });
});
```

The output of the json AJAX for city looks like:

```
<option value="1">New York City</option>
<option value="2">Albany</option>
```

Similarly for buildings:

```
<option value="1">Empire State Building</option>
<option value="2">Penn Station</option>
```

The issue here is that when I select a city, the building select box resets and all of the options disappears. I know this is because the two getjson call is in the same function. How do I make it so that the selection of city and building are independent from each other?

Once state has been changed and select, I should only need to call $.getjson once until someone changes the state value again.

Comment: Change "$('form').on("change", "select", function(){" to "$('form').on("change", "select[name='State']", function(){" and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the relevant code that is "resetting" the city and building checkboxes:

```
$('form').on("change", "select", function(){
    var current_index = $(this).index();
    if($(this).eq(current_index).val() == 'Z') {
    } else {
        current.siblings('.city option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');
        current.siblings('.building option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');
    }
});
```

So any time you change ANY dropdown, as long as the value isn't `Z`, you are setting the city and state to the first option.

---

Instead of doing `$('form').on("change", "select", function(){})` and then `if` statements for each input, why don't you monitor the change event for each input directly:

```
<select id="selState" name="State" class="state">
  <option selected disabled>Choose a State</option>
  <option value="1">California</option>
  <option value="2">New York</option>
</select>
<select id="selCity" name="City" class="city" disabled="true">
  <option value="Z">Select a city</option>
</select>
<select id="selBuilding" name="Building" class="building" disabled="true">
  <option value="Z">Select a building</option>
</select>
```

If you want to populate the city and building dropdowns based on the state dropdown, and do nothing when the city and building dropdowns are changed, you would do something like this:

```
$('form').on("change", "#selState", function(){
  //get state id
  var stateid = $(this).val();
  //Get cities for selected state
  $.getJSON('get_city/', {state_id: stateid}, function(data) {
    //add "Select a city option"
    $('#selCity').html('<option value="Z">Select a city</option>');
    //Loop through returned cities.
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
      //add city to select
      $('#selCity').append('<option value="'+data[i].pk+'">'+data[i].fields['name']+'</option>');
    }
  });
  //Get buildings for selected state
  $.getJSON('get_building/', {state_id: stateid}, function(data) {
    //add "Select a building option"
    $('#selCity').html('<option value="Z">Select a building</option>');
    //Loop through returned buildings.
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
      //add building to select
      $('#selBuilding').append('<option value="'+data[i].pk+'">'+data[i].fields['name']+'</option>');
    }
  });
  //enable other select
  $('#selCity').attr('disabled', false);
  $('#selBuilding').attr('disabled', false);
})
```

Comment: when the user first select the state, I want to pull the city and building options at the same time. That's why I wrapped it around the same event. Does that make sense? Once it's pulled, I shouldn't need to pull $getjson for city and building unless the state value changes. can I just listen for the state selection box?

Comment: So the event is listening for a change to the specified element. If you want to tie two calls (city and building) to the change event for the state box, there is no reason you cannot do that.  Just put the second JSON call right after the city one.  And yes, you can remove the change event detection for the city and building boxes if you don't need anything to happen when they *change*.  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: If this is still confusing, please update your question with the full desired workflow ("Changing the state will populate the city and building drop downs", etc)

Comment: Isn't that what I have done in the original code? When there is a change or select in the form, there is a call to $.getjson for city, and $getjson call for building? The issue is that once the initial call has been made. Subsequent changes to the city and building selection elements erase the selection value already made in either building and city. I think that's the issue I'm trying to address. or may be I'm not understand what you are saying.

Comment: Yes, that is happening because you are doing the JSON calls (and all the logic) any time ANY `<select>` element is changed.  You only want to do it when the State dropdown is changed.  Right?